# Mathematica 10.2 - Window not responding

Tags: gnome, mutter

I have Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome-Shell running and use Mathematica 10.2. Whenever I open a mathematica file and select some lines in it, I get a message from the system that `mathematica is not responding. You may choose to wait a short while for it to continue or force the application to quit entirely.` This problem is also described at [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1498543). However, it is stated there, that they cannot do anything about it. Now there is a statement at the [redhat bugzilla page](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=981149) that one only has to change one line in the delete.c file from mutter, to deactivate the whole message. This hack would be a sufficient solution for me.

The question now is, how do I implement the proposed change in the file? I cannot find a delete.c file on my computer. Do I have to compile mutter myself?

```
diff --git a/src/core/delete.c b/src/core/delete.c
index 141cd49..d8a126e 100644
--- a/src/core/delete.c
+++ b/src/core/delete.c
@@ -98,6 +98,8 @@ show_delete_dialog (MetaWindow *window,
               "Got delete ping timeout for %s\n",
               window->desc);

+  return;
+
   if (window->dialog_pid >= 0)
     {
       present_existing_delete_dialog (window, timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

The snippet you've posted is a diff patch. The idea is that you download the source code to mutter, which will include the `delete.c` file. You then use the `patch` tool to apply the diff patch, recompile it, and reinstall it.

This can be a pretty complicated process, though. You may need to install a bunch of build tool packages, maybe including the source code for related packages. I found a couple of general tutorials if you're interested:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/06/install-from-source/

http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/index.html

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...